# CSS - Stop line intersecting the circle

Tags: html, css

Can anybody tell me how to stop this line from crossing the circle?
[image: this]

I want it like this. i.e no line inside the circle.

[image: this]

The background (in this case of li tag) is going to be the transparent.

```css
#project-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* Messing with positioning element on page */
  /* min-height or top margin allows for full use */
  /* min-height:600px;
  */
  margin: 420px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#orbital-menu {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;
  z-index: 8900 !important;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

#orbital-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  /* -webkit-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 650ms linear;
  transition: all 650ms linear;*/
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative !important;
  clear: both !important;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  transition: all 650ms ease-out;*/
  /* NAME: ORBITAL-BLOCK-1 */
  /* STATUS: BEGIN */
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li.orb {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  opacity: 1;
  clear: both !important;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: calc(70px * -0.5) 0 0 calc(70px * -0.5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #af6a79;
  z-index: 8900 !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;*/
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li.orb+.orb {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li {
  border: 10px solid #ff326a;
  z-index: 8950 !important;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] {
  /*opacity: 0.75;*/
  opacity: 1;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li {
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
  opacity: 1;
}

#orbital-menu:before,
#orbital-menu:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  clear: both !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 550ms linear;
  transition: all 550ms linear;*/
}

#orbital-menu,
#orbital-menu:focus {
  /* things won't work in IE 10 without this declaration */
}

#orbital-menu:before {
  /*height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;*/
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin: -65px 0 0 -63px;
  border: 2px solid #a06270;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/map.png');
  background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;*/
}

#orbital-menu {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: -145px 0 0 -143px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  border: 2px solid #af6a79;
}


/*ul.orb-master span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
    left: 45px;
}*/

ul.orb-master span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 137px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  line-height: 12px;
}

nav#orbital-menu ul.orb-master {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(2) i {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(2) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 24px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(3) i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(3) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 24px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(4) i {
  transform: rotate(-270deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: -12px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(4) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(5) i {
  transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(5) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

ul.orb-master li.orb.orbturnred {
  background: #b30122 !important;
  border: 2px solid #b30122 !important;
}

ul.orb-master li.orb.orbturnred i {
  color: #fff !important;
  ;
  top: 20px !important;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pm"].orb.orbturnred i {
  top: -7px !important;
  left: -2px;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pa"].orb.orbturnred i {
  left: 12px;
  top: 8px !important;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="ps"].orb.orbturnred i {
  left: -12px;
  top: 8px !important;
}

ul.orb-master {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  list-style: none;
}

nav#orbital-menu>i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 60px;
  clear: both !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  /* -webkit-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 550ms linear;
    transition: all 550ms linear;*/
}

ul.orb-master.orbturnred {
  /* background-color: #b30122 !important;
    border: none !important;*/
}

ul.orb-master.orbturnred span {
  color: #fff !important;
  /*     top: 145px; */
}

i.fa.fa-map.icoturnwhite {
  color: white;
}

ul.orb-master li {
  /*background-image: url(https://mentoreurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Cogs_edited-with-gradient.jpg);*/
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /*background: #fff !important;*/
}

div#project-wrapper {
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 470px;
  width: 470px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 42px);
  top: -28px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -60px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pr"].orb.orbturnred i {
  top: 22px !important;
}

nav#orbital-menu.middleorbturnred:before {
  background-color: #b30122 !important;
  border: 2px solid #b30122 !important;
}

#orbital-menu:before {
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.9.8" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="project-wrapper"><span>Your Strategy</span><span>Review</span><span>Design</span><span>Delivery</span>
  <nav id="orbital-menu" class=""><i class="fa fa-map"></i>
    <ul class="orb-master" data-children="4"><span>MENTOR BLUEPRINT</span>
      <li class="orb" name="pa"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Acceleration</b></i> </li>
      <li class="orb" name="pm"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Portfolio Management</b></i> </li>
      <li class="orb" name="ps"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Setup</b></i> </li>
      <li class="orb" name="pr"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Review</b></i> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try creating a fiddle here on stack overflow

Comment: The easiest way is to make the background white. If  you can't use it, you'll need to use SVG instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a tough cookie, but I enjoyed the challenge! I had to change up some of the existing CSS by moving the large circle border to the `#orbital-menu:after` pseudo-element and tweaking margins.

`transform-origin` isn't necessary since you aren't doing rotations on `#orbital-menu`

```
#orbital-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    margin: -140px 0 0 -140px;
    z-index: 8900 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}

#orbital-menu:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #af6a79;
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 34% 0, 50% 10%, 66% 0, 100% 0, 100% 34%, 90% 50%, 100% 66%, 100% 100%, 66% 100%, 50% 90%, 34% 100%, 0 100%, 0 66%, 10% 50%, 0 34%);
}
```

The trick here is the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property. It will reshape the element after border is applied. I utilized a [clip-path maker](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to generate the polygon to clip out the border where it intersected with the other circles. This could not have been applied to the element itself, otherwise the children orb elements would have been clipped too.

[image]

I also cleaned up your `#project-wrapper > span` CSS to reduce redundancy (and get you started):

```
#project-wrapper>span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font: italic 700 18px initial;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(1) {
  left: calc(50% - 42px);
  top: -28px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  right: -60px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
}
```

And I realize you have *waaaayy* too many other redundant CSS that you can cleanup:

- Extracting all common properties within `:nth-of-type` selector
- Removing all prefixed properties to which most browsers have already adopted (reference [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com))

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://mentoreurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Cogs_edited-with-gradient.jpg);
  color: #797979;
}

#project-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* Messing with positioning element on page */
  /* min-height or top margin allows for full use */
  /* min-height:600px;
  */
  margin: 420px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#orbital-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: -140px 0 0 -140px;
  z-index: 8900 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

#orbital-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  /* -webkit-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 650ms linear;
  transition: all 650ms linear;*/
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative !important;
  clear: both !important;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  transition: all 650ms ease-out;*/
  /* NAME: ORBITAL-BLOCK-1 */
  /* STATUS: BEGIN */
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li.orb {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  opacity: 1;
  clear: both !important;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: calc(70px * -0.5) 0 0 calc(70px * -0.5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #af6a79;
  z-index: 8900 !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;*/
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li.orb+.orb {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li {
  border: 10px solid #ff326a;
  z-index: 8950 !important;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] {
  /*opacity: 0.75;*/
  opacity: 1;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li {
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
  opacity: 1;
}

#orbital-menu:before,
#orbital-menu:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  clear: both !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 550ms linear;
  transition: all 550ms linear;*/
}

#orbital-menu,
#orbital-menu:focus {
  /* things won't work in IE 10 without this declaration */
}

#orbital-menu:before {
  /*height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;*/
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin: -65px 0 0 -63px;
  border: 2px solid #a06270;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
  /*background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/map.png');
  background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;*/
}

#orbital-menu:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #af6a79;
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 34% 0, 50% 10%, 66% 0, 100% 0, 100% 34%, 90% 50%, 100% 66%, 100% 100%, 66% 100%, 50% 90%, 34% 100%, 0 100%, 0 66%, 10% 50%, 0 34%);
}

ul.orb-master span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 137px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  line-height: 12px;
}

nav#orbital-menu ul.orb-master {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(2) i {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(2) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 24px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(3) i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(3) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 24px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(4) i {
  transform: rotate(-270deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: -12px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(4) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(5) i {
  transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(5) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

ul.orb-master li.orb.orbturnred {
  background: #b30122 !important;
  border: 2px solid #b30122 !important;
}

ul.orb-master li.orb.orbturnred i {
  color: #fff !important;
  ;
  top: 20px !important;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pm"].orb.orbturnred i {
  top: -7px !important;
  left: -2px;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pa"].orb.orbturnred i {
  left: 12px;
  top: 8px !important;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="ps"].orb.orbturnred i {
  left: -12px;
  top: 8px !important;
}

ul.orb-master {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  list-style: none;
}

nav#orbital-menu>i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 60px;
  clear: both !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  /* -webkit-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 550ms linear;
    transition: all 550ms linear;*/
}

ul.orb-master.orbturnred {
  /* background-color: #b30122 !important;
    border: none !important;*/
}

ul.orb-master.orbturnred span {
  color: #fff !important;
  /*     top: 145px; */
}

i.fa.fa-map.icoturnwhite {
  color: white;
}

ul.orb-master li {
  /*background-image: url(https://mentoreurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Cogs_edited-with-gradient.jpg);*/
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /*background: #fff !important;*/
}

div#project-wrapper {
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 470px;
  width: 470px;
}

#project-wrapper>span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font: italic 700 18px initial;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(1) {
  left: calc(50% - 42px);
  top: -28px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  right: -60px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pr"].orb.orbturnred i {
  top: 22px !important;
}

nav#orbital-menu.middleorbturnred:before {
  background-color: #b30122 !important;
  border: 2px solid #b30122 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="project-wrapper">
  <span>Your Strategy</span>
  <span>Review</span>
  <span>Design</span>
  <span>Delivery</span>
  <nav id="orbital-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-map"></i>
    <ul class="orb-master" data-children="4"><span>MENTOR BLUEPRINT</span>
      <li class="orb" name="pa">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Acceleration</b></i>
      </li>
      <li class="orb" name="pm">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Portfolio Management</b></i>
      </li>
      <li class="orb" name="ps">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Setup</b></i>
      </li>
      <li class="orb" name="pr">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Review</b></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Added some styles to the `body` element in the snippet to match your site.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Add a `background-color` property to `#orbital-menu:after` if you want to play with the clipping to see it in action.

Comment: you should merge both your answer or delete the first one

Comment: @TemaniAfif They are completely different solutions based on different assumptions not included in the original question. (The comments were deleted)

Comment: but you are the same user :) we don't add different answers. We make one answer where we add the different solutions

Comment: I don't wish to confuse readers with mixed solutions; hence the distinction. I don't expect the other answer to get upvoted though.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change the background of the `li.orb` circles to white since the transparent background that is currently set will show the lines behind it.

```
#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li.orb {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Also, you may want to set the following backgrounds (for the text labels) to white as well so you can easily read the text without the lines interfering:

```
#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(3) i b,
#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(5) i b {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
#project-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* Messing with positioning element on page */
  /* min-height or top margin allows for full use */
  /* min-height:600px;
  */
  margin: 420px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#orbital-menu {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;
  z-index: 8900 !important;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

#orbital-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  /* -webkit-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 650ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 650ms linear;
  transition: all 650ms linear;*/
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative !important;
  clear: both !important;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 650ms ease-out;
  transition: all 650ms ease-out;*/
  /* NAME: ORBITAL-BLOCK-1 */
  /* STATUS: BEGIN */
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li.orb {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  opacity: 1;
  clear: both !important;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: calc(70px * -0.5) 0 0 calc(70px * -0.5);
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #af6a79;
  z-index: 8900 !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;*/
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li.orb+.orb {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li {
  border: 10px solid #ff326a;
  z-index: 8950 !important;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
  animation-delay: 1250ms !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master li ul.first-satellite-orb[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -ms-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -moz-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -o-animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  animation-delay: 850ms !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(1).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(2).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(3).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(140px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4).satellite-orb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(65px) !important;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li:nth-of-type(4).satellite-orb {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, inset 0 0 px #FFF;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] {
  /*opacity: 0.75;*/
  opacity: 1;
}

#orbital-menu ul.orb-master[data-children="4"] li {
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
  opacity: 1;
}

#orbital-menu:before,
#orbital-menu:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  clear: both !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  /*-webkit-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 550ms linear;
  transition: all 550ms linear;*/
}

#orbital-menu,
#orbital-menu:focus {
  /* things won't work in IE 10 without this declaration */
}

#orbital-menu:before {
  /*height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -70px;*/
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin: -65px 0 0 -63px;
  border: 2px solid #a06270;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/map.png');
  background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;*/
}

#orbital-menu {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: -145px 0 0 -143px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  border: 2px solid #af6a79;
}


/*ul.orb-master span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
    left: 45px;
}*/

ul.orb-master span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 137px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  line-height: 12px;
}

nav#orbital-menu ul.orb-master {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(2) i {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(2) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 24px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(3) i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(3) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 24px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: white;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(4) i {
  transform: rotate(-270deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: -12px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(4) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(5) i {
  transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li:nth-child(5) i b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: white;
}

ul.orb-master li.orb.orbturnred {
  background: #b30122 !important;
  border: 2px solid #b30122 !important;
}

ul.orb-master li.orb.orbturnred i {
  color: #fff !important;
  ;
  top: 20px !important;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pm"].orb.orbturnred i {
  top: -7px !important;
  left: -2px;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pa"].orb.orbturnred i {
  left: 12px;
  top: 8px !important;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="ps"].orb.orbturnred i {
  left: -12px;
  top: 8px !important;
}

ul.orb-master {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  list-style: none;
}

nav#orbital-menu>i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 60px;
  clear: both !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  /* -webkit-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 550ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 550ms linear;
    transition: all 550ms linear;*/
}

ul.orb-master.orbturnred {
  /* background-color: #b30122 !important;
    border: none !important;*/
}

ul.orb-master.orbturnred span {
  color: #fff !important;
  /*     top: 145px; */
}

i.fa.fa-map.icoturnwhite {
  color: white;
}

ul.orb-master li {
  /*background-image: url(https://mentoreurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Cogs_edited-with-gradient.jpg);*/
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /*background: #fff !important;*/
}

div#project-wrapper {
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 470px;
  width: 470px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 42px);
  top: -28px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -60px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#project-wrapper>span:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#orbital-menu>ul>li[name="pr"].orb.orbturnred i {
  top: 22px !important;
}

nav#orbital-menu.middleorbturnred:before {
  background-color: #b30122 !important;
  border: 2px solid #b30122 !important;
}

#orbital-menu:before {
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.9.8" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="project-wrapper"><span>Your Strategy</span><span>Review</span><span>Design</span><span>Delivery</span>
  <nav id="orbital-menu" class=""><i class="fa fa-map"></i>
    <ul class="orb-master" data-children="4"><span>MENTOR BLUEPRINT</span>
      <li class="orb" name="pa"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Acceleration</b></i> </li>
      <li class="orb" name="pm"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Portfolio Management</b></i> </li>
      <li class="orb" name="ps"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Setup</b></i> </li>
      <li class="orb" name="pr"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"><b>Program Review</b></i> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Edit:** This solution would only work if the background was white, which made the problem trivial. I have provided another answer to tend to the new information that the background is an image.

Comment: Is the downvote really necessary? If it's about answering OPs question, it would help others that may not have the same requirements.